# Differential Equation - $y'=|y|+1, y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $y'=|y|+1, y(0)=0$.

Suppose $y$ is a solution on an interval $I$. Let $x\in I$.

If $y(x)\ge 0$ then $$y'(x)=|y(x)|+1\iff y'(x)=y(x)+1\iff \frac{y'(x)}{y(x)+1}=1\\ \iff \ln (y(x)+1)=x+C\iff y(x)+1=e^{x+C}\\ \iff y(x)=e^{x+C}-1$$

Then $y(0)=0\implies C=0$. So $y(x)=e^x-1$ if $y(x)\ge 0$.

If $y(x)\leq 0$ then $y(x)=1-e^x$.

Now I want to say $y(x)=\begin{cases} e^x-1, \text{if } x\ge 0\\1-e^x, \text{if } x\leq 0\end{cases}$

Is this correct? Is there only one solution?

Comment: I think you mean to switch your inequalities in your piecewise definition of $y(x)$. To check if a solution is correct, you need to substitue the answer back into the original differential equation. To check uniqueness, you need to be on the lookout for "trivial" solutions that can crop up when we divide by zero. As you are working with $|y| +1$ in the denominator, these will not occur, so you can be (fairly) confident that this is the only solution.

Comment: @KrisWilliams tks for noticing the typo. but how do I really make sure there aren't any other solutions. just looking at trivial solutions doesn't seem rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my solution above is correct.

there are a few details missing:

it is necessary to show that $y(x)\leq 0\iff x\leq0$ and $y(x)\ge 0\iff x\ge 0$ which allows me to define $y$ the way I do.

also it is necessary to check that $y$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and it is because:

$$\lim _{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x-0}=1=\lim _{x\to 0^-}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x-0}$$

Comment: good my friend.