# Differential Equation - $y'=5|y|^{4/5}, y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

in the spirit of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377443/differential-equation-y-y1-y0-0) I ask about this one.

$y'=5|y|^{4/5}, y(0)=0$

If $y> 0$ then $$y'=5|y|^{4/5}\iff y'=5^{-1}y^{4/5}\iff 5^{-1}y'y^{-4/5}=1\iff y^{1/5}=x+C\\ \iff y=\left(x+C\right)^{5}$$

Now $y(0)=0\implies C=0$. But what I did above is for $y>0$, so I can I justify this?

Comment: Look at $y'=5y^{4/5}\iff 5y'y^{-4/5}=1$

Comment: @Cortizol tks, I corrected it now, but I still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you will need for handling absolute values of functions to solve separately the $y>0$ and $y<0$ cases.

For this one,

1. $y>0$: you solved it correctly! You have $y(x) = x^5, \text{ }\,\forall y>0 \Rightarrow \forall x>0$.
2. $y<0$: same process goes here but you need to integrate $y'=5(-y)^{4/5}$. Changing $y \rightarrow -y$, you have $y(x) = -x^5, \text{ }\,\forall y<0 \Rightarrow \forall x<0$.

Your final solution is the piecewise function
$$
\boxed{y(x) = \begin{cases}
-x^5 & \text{ if }\,x<0 \\
x^5 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.}
$$

You can use the same reasoning [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379401/differential-equation-y-4y3-4-y0-0).