# Differential Equation $y'=4|y|^{3/4}, y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377443/differential-equation-y-y1-y0-0) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377458/differential-equation-y-5y4-5-y0-0).

$$y'=4|y|^{3/4}, y(0)=0$$

Let $f$ be a solution of the equation on $I$

Let $x\in I$

If $f(x)>0$, then $f'(x)=4f(x)^{3/4}$, so $f(x)^{-3/4}f(x)=4$, so $f(x)^{1/4}=x+C, C\in \mathbb{R}$.

So $f(x)=(x+C)^4$.

If $f(x)<0$, then $-f(x)=(x+K)^4$, $K\in \mathbb{R}$.

everything correct so far?

and now what do I do? how do I get from here to a solution? I still have to consider what happens when $f(x)=0$ (somewhere, but not everywhere).

I also need domains.

What do I do from here?

Comment: takning integration with respect to x , since $ y=y(x) $ then we have  the implicit relation $ 4x+C=|y|^{1/4} $ applying the condition $ y(0)=0 $ we get   4.0+C= |y(0)|^{1/4}=0 $ so $ C=0 $

Comment: @JoseGarcia doesnt seem to work: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+4%7Cy%28x%29%7C%5E%283%2F4%29dx

Comment: Try and express $|x|$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$, which you will be able to integrate, just don't reduce the root and the square.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377458/differential-equation-y-5y4-5-y0-0).